# Change order of items in ListView

Tags: android

I use bind of `ListView` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`. It works fine, but I need show last selected item of listView on the top of listView.
I store the position of selected item in shared preferences, but how can I replace this from current position to the top of the listView?

Comment: which type of layout you are using?

Comment: simply change the order of the rows placed in your Cursor (last parameter in a query method)

Comment: Layouts: `ListView` and `LinearLayout` for items; How can I get `ArrayList` from ListView or SimpleCursorAdapter?;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the selected item from your list and add it to "0" position, then refresh your list adapter.

```
String item = new String (yourSelectedItem); //replace "String" with your item type.
dataList.remove(item); //dataList is your arrayList with the list's data
dataList.add(0, item);

listView.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: How can I get `ArrayList` from `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.items_var_entry, cursor, columns, to, 0); ListView listView = findViewById(//some id);listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Comment: you can do an arrayList from your cursor, then you can use a normal adapter for your list.


do {
 dataList list = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
       list.add(cursor.getString(i));
 }
 retList.add(list);
} while (cursor.moveToNext());

Comment: Yeah, but I hoped that there is way to do it in current implementation. In any case great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can update the last selected item in data base with a field like SCORE ,
and get a cursor with SCORE in DESC order

Comment: Yeah, but I think should exist way to do it without forming special queries. I mean, I just need to reorder `ListView`. Isn't it trivial task?